# joints not showing up in rviz

Tags: ros, rviz, joint

First of all, I'm not a native speaker sorry for my English, I'll try to fully demonstrate my problems. I wrote a urdf file that contains a base, four wheels, and a lidar. Everything is showing up normally as it should in Gazebo, but when I open up Rviz all my wheels will be in the center of my base, seems like the joints are somehow missing, I tried to publish joint state publisher gui to move my joints and got no luck since it's all stuck in the center. Any help is appreciated Ty.`

[image: Gazebo]
[image: Rviz]
[image: one of my wheel joint's code]

Comment: Welcome to Robotics Stack Exchange! Two comments: 1. It is better to paste the URDF in the text form rather than sharing a screenshot. Please note that images are not text-searchable. 2. Please share us complete information, such as which package and commands you executed. My guess is that you do not have a `joint_state_publisher` thus the bot can not be rendered completely.

Answer (score 1):

As already mentioned, it seems that your are missing the tf2 tree, which rviz needs to render your robot.
You'll get this by adding robot_state_publisher to your launch file.

A tutorial of the robot_state_publisher with a python script can, e.g., be found in on [docs.ros.org](https://docs.ros.org/en/iron/Tutorials/Intermediate/URDF/Using-URDF-with-Robot-State-Publisher.html?highlight=robot_state_publisher) or in the demo repository of [ros2_control](https://control.ros.org/master/doc/ros2_control_demos/example_2/doc/userdoc.html) or shipped with the [gazebo_ros2_control_demos](https://control.ros.org/master/doc/gz_ros2_control/doc/index.html), what might be helpful for your setup as well.